# Specify Python type scenarios on a function

Tags: python, python-typing

I would like to have a **mypy**-accepted constructor, based on this example:

```py
N = Union[Network4, Network6]
A = Union[Address4, Address6]

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, network: N, address: A) -> None:
        self.network: N = network
        self.address: A = address
```

As you see in this example, you can mix the IPv4 and IPv6 in one call, but I want to accept the appropriate pairs only.

Can I, and how can I describe that with pure type-hinting (without `@overload`)?

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you don't want to use `@overload`? You could do something involving `TypeDict`s (passing in a dictionary of arguments), but that would be more verbose than using `@overload`.

Comment: Ignore `mypy` for a moment: from a type signature to a function point of view, two different arguments have zero relations to each other as there is no standard in Python that defines that, the only way you can make this work is to provide a (named)tuple of the supported kind that explicitly bind together the two related arguments as one clearly concrete thing that gets passed in.  Alternatively, just `@overload` to make it perfectly clear what the accepted type signatures are.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, Because the original code has started w/o types, and I wanted to hint (only) this correlation between the parameters... without introducing multiple constructors and extracting the common part into a third function.

Comment: @metatoaster, yap, I've come to the same conclusion... thank you